# Luis Dialog creation issue

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

hi I am implementing one bot using LUIS, so I want to take input from user & give answer, if user enters incomplete info. then I want to reply him with another dialog which I suppose to get from Luis json.

I had implemented the same in Luis. But after the changes of the Luis UI. I am not able to get the steps to implement the above mentioned dynamic conversation in Luis.

Looking guidance on the same. Thanks in advance.

In the old version of luis, I had designed the Luis Application which was handling the action and I was getting the dialog like below:

"dialog": { "prompt": "which food do you want?", "parameterName": "Food Name", "parameterType": "foodName", "contextId": "ae5de259-6a9b-476c-bbb8-1be7fceba761", "status": "Question" } }

But in the current Luis UI(Updated one), I am not getting the steps to implement the same. I am looking the same type of dialog (mentioned above), if user is not enters incomplete info.

[image: Not getting the below highlighted option in New Luis UI]

Regards,
Lax

Answer (score 4):

Action Binding and Action Parameters were deprecated (as mentioned in the UI). You cannot do that within LUIS anymore.

The good news is that a [library](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/Blog-LUISActionBinding) was created to support that scenario so you will be able to accomplish pretty much the same, in a bot, a web or even a console app.

Here is a set of blog posts that explain how this library works:

- [Implementing LUIS Action Binding on the Client](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/04/03/Luis-Action-Binding-Bot/)
- [Luis Action Binding for Web Apps](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/04/06/Luis-Action-Binding-Web/)
- [Luis Action Binding for Console Apps](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/04/18/Luis-Action-Binding-Console/)