# Correct approach with follow-up questions in a LUIS app

Tags: nlp, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a chatbot with the botframework and the NLP service LUIS.

Can anyone explain here what could be the correct approach if you want an app/chatbot to answer follow-up questions based on the context of the previous one?

Let me put and example:

```
[me]: I want to buy a Ford car
[bot]: Here are the list of different cars we have....
[me]: what about a red one?
[bot]: sure! I added the red color to your car
[me]: I also want bluetooth
.....
```

As you can see, the questions about color and Bluetooth or whatever other qualities that a car can have, make no sense if you don't know the context of the conversation.

Should this be done with a waterfall approach on the botframework or should this be done with LUIS utterances? And how can we achieve this? I believe it has to be done through LUIS but I'm not sure about the correct approach.

EDIT to clarify:

I understand this could be accomplished implementing bindingActions as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283516/luis-dialog-creation-issue), but that will imply I have to code every different use case (in this case I would have to code one bindAction for colors, one for #doors, one for type of motor, etc), and what I want is the bot to answers spontaneous questions.

The answer below got me thinking about implementing a waterfall dialog and in the second step of the dialog route the question to a QnAmaker services with the different answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Luis Dialog creation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283516/luis-dialog-creation-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct using waterfall - I'm assuming you're developing with the Node.js SDK, in which case please check out the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow) to read about how to implement waterfalls to manage your dialog.

If you're using .NET SDK, you would use [form flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced).

Your LUIS service should just return an 'intent' that the user wishes to buy a car for your use case, after that, you need to direct the conversation flow via the dialog in the bot. For 'follow up' questions, your current dialog needs to resolve, or you can implement a global message handler.

This [article](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/10/dialog-management-qna-luis-scorables/) showcases examples for .NET, but you could apply the same logic for a node.js bot. In that article, LUIS is used to direct the user to different dialogs, based on what the returned intent is.

Hope this helped, good luck!

Comment: Thank you Matthew! I have the doubt on how to resolve the follow-up questions without coding every use case possible. For that I could try to call a QnAMaker service with the questions and answers, and route the questions to that service, otherwise I don't know how to resolve every different question that can be made.